# list index out of range, whenever I change the list size

Tags: python, list, indexing, range, reverse

Im trying to rotate a list of list 90 degrees. For example, change this:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

to

```
[[7,4,1], [8,5,2],[9,6,3]]
```

Visually:

```
[[1,2,3],           [[7,4,1],
 [4,5,6],    -->     [8,5,2],
 [7,8,9]]            [9,6,3]]
```

Whenever I change the list size to be more elements or less it always says the index is out of range? What is going on?

```
def rotate(list1):
    bigList = [] #create a list that we will append on to
    for i in (range(len(list1)+1)): #loop through the list looking at the indexes
        newList = []
        for j in reversed(range(len(list1))): #reverse that list
            newList.append(list1[j][i])
        bigList.append((newList)) #append the elements to the bigList reversed
    return bigList
```

Comment: Is your indentation posted in here correct?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I don't think it is, and also his list is not right.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Should be correct now, sorry about that still getting used to the code blocks while typing it in

Comment: Don't use built in type `list` as a variable name

Comment: Why you need len(list1)+1 ?

Comment: I'm assuming this is due tomorrow? Make sure not to use list in the name.

Comment: @KenCheung I originally had it without +1 I wanted to see if it would that would work if I had a bigger list

Comment: Did you delete code on accident?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing can be very easily done in a single line using `reversed` and `zip` . Actual issue in your code given below in this answer.

Example -

```
list(zip(*reversed(yourlist)))
```

You do not need the `list(...)` for *Python 2.x*, as `zip()` returns a list in *Python 2.x* .

Demo -

```
>>> list(zip(*reversed([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])))
[(7, 4, 1), (8, 5, 2), (9, 6, 3)]
>>> list(zip(*reversed([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])))
[(9, 5, 1), (10, 6, 2), (11, 7, 3), (12, 8, 4)]
```

If you want a list of lists, instead of list of tuple, you can use list comprehension (or `map(list, zip(*reversed(....)))`). Example -

```
[list(x) for x in zip(*reversed(yourlist))]
```

Demo -

```
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(*reversed([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]))]
[[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(*reversed([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]))]
[[9, 5, 1], [10, 6, 2], [11, 7, 3], [12, 8, 4]]
```

`*` is the syntax for unpacking , so the list returned by `reversed()` is unpacked into `zip()` and passed as separate arguments to it.

Then `zip()` function combines the elements of each of its argument at its corresponding index (like all first arguments together , all second arguments together, etc.) , Hence we get the result we need.

---

The actual issue for the original code occurred because of the following line -

```
for i in (range(len(list1)+1)):
```

You are looping till `len(list1) + 1` , hence eventually you try to access elements like `list1[0][len(list1)]` , but  that does not exist in your case.

Assuming that `list1`'s sublist all will have same amount of elements, what you really need there would be `len(list1[0])` . Example -

```
def rotate(list1):
    bigList = [] #create a list that we will append on to
    for i in (range(len(list1[0]))): #loop through the list looking at the indexes
        newList = []
        for j in reversed(range(len(list1))): #reverse that list
            newList.append(list1[j][i])
        bigList.append((newList)) #append the elements to the bigList reversed
    return bigList
```

Demo -

```
>>> def rotate(list1):
...     bigList = [] #create a list that we will append on to
...     for i in (range(len(list1[0]))): #loop through the list looking at the indexes
...         newList = []
...         for j in reversed(range(len(list1))): #reverse that list
...             newList.append(list1[j][i])
...         bigList.append((newList)) #append the elements to the bigList reversed
...     return bigList
...
>>> rotate([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
[[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
>>> rotate([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
[[9, 5, 1], [10, 6, 2], [11, 7, 3], [12, 8, 4]]
```

---

Comment: Could you please explain whats going on in the line `list(zip(*reversed(...)))` and what the `*` means here?

Comment: `*` is the syntax for unpacking , so the list returned by `reversed()` is unpacked into `zip()` and passed as separate arguments to it. 
Then `zip()` function combines the elements of each of its argument at its corresponding index (like all first arguments together , all second arguments together, etc.) , Hence we get the result we need. Updated this in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for i in (range(len(list1)+1))
```

to

```
for i in (range(len(list1)))
```

and it should work

Comment: it doesn't work if I have more elements in the list of list, for example it crashes on [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `for i` line to:

```
for i in (range(len(list1))):
```

then it gives the expected result.

Note that your code only works for n-by-n lists and not for n-by-m lists

Typical example of an [off by one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) ;-)